# Detect Newly Loaded Chunks Using Command Blocks/Redstone

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I'm currently using the latest 16w20a snapshot, but AFAIK, anything that works for this problem in 1.9 will work here. Basically, I'm trying to detect when new chunks are loaded. This way I can `/spreadplayers` some armor stands around the player and generate some structures in the new chunks. The problem is, I don't know how to detect when there are new chunks loaded.

I thought it would help to detect when the armor stands have become unloaded, which I thought I could do by seeing whether `/testfor` or `/execute` fail on them...but they never do. I've ensured they're in unloaded chunks, and still both of those commands are successful and I don't understand how.

So, in conclsion, how can I test for the generation of new chunks? I can't just spread the armor stands everywhere all the time, because that would lead to structures generating where there are already structures from the last spread.

Comment: /setblock and conditional cmd blocks, if its out of the world, it will not work

Comment: I was about to ask if there was a way to do it that won't modify the world, but I just realized I can /tp them to y=0 and set the block to bedrock. Assuming /setblock doesn't fail when setting to the same as the existing block (I have to check that), it won't modify the world and it should give me the information I need. Thank you!

Comment: /setblock does fail when it does nothing

Comment: I'm closing this is a duplicate of a newer question, because this one mentions a lot of problems that don't exist anymore, the newer one is slightly broader (also includes Singleplayer world opening detection) and I have already answered it (twice) before I found this one.